# Ansible: looping over with multiple {{ items }}

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory file with the following variables:

```
vpc_public_net1=["10.30.0.0/24","AZ=a"]
vpc_public_net2=["10.30.1.0/24","AZ=b"]
```

I can extract AZ value with `"{{ item[1].split('=')[1] }}"`

I'm having difficulties extracting both subnet and `AZ` using the same 
ansible task

my Ansible code:

```
- name: Create Public Subnets
  ec2_vpc_subnet: state="present"
                  vpc_id="{{ vpc_id }}"
                  cidr="{{ item.subnet }}"
                  az="{{ item.az }}"
                  region="{{ aws_region }}"
                  aws_access_key="{{ aws_access_key }}"
                  aws_secret_key="{{ aws_secret_key }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine as a dictionary:

```
vpc_public_net1='{"subnet": "10.30.0.0/24", "az": "a"}'
vpc_public_net2='{"subnet": "10.30.1.0/24", "az": "b"}'
```

and:

```
- name: Create Public Subnets
  ec2_vpc_subnet:
    state: present
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
    cidr: "{{ item.subnet }}"
    az: "{{ item.az }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ vpc_public_net1 }}"
    - "{{ vpc_public_net2 }}"
```